# Quick way to drop giant MySQL column

Tags: mysql, rds, diskspace

We had a bit of a site emergency today when we ran out of space on our RDS MySQL database instance.  This was due to me trying to populate a newly added MEDIUMTEXT column in a database table that has 30 million rows.  Oops.

One thing that compounded the problem, I think, was that after I realised what had made it run out of space, and killed the `update` process, I then tried to drop the new column, foolishly thinking that would free up some space.

This was actually bound to not work, because when you drop a column in Mysql you don't get the disk space back, at least not without doing some extra housekeeping.

But, i think it actually made things worse by increasing the size of a temp file in the DB, presumably that is holding the column data, to make the process transactionable - acting like a wastebasket, effectively, to give recoverabality to the deleted data.

This then made it run out of space even more (I'd given it some more space via the AWS console).

So, not a great morning (this was with my kids screaming in my ear at 7am, as well).

Is there a way to just get rid of a column which is a) quick, even for large tables b) doesn't make any extra temp data and c) actually gives you some disk space back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to *reduce* the usage of your storage without temporarily taking more space is to DROP TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE, and even that will reduce space only if you have the option `innodb_file_per_table=ON` (this is on by default since MySQL 5.6).

Many types of ALTER TABLE operations make a temporary copy of the table, which creates a new tablespace. Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html and notice every type of ALTER TABLE that is noted with "Rebuilds table: Yes"

Rebuilding the table means creating a new table, copying all the data from the old table to the new table, while adapting to changes in columns in the new table, then swapping the new table for the old table, and finally dropping the old table. This takes time for a large table, and temporarily requires storing both the table and the new table simultaneously.

Basically, any alteration that changes the size of a row, like adding/dropping columns, changing datatypes of columns, or even changing the nullability of columns, rebuilds the table. There's no way to drop a column quickly or without temporarily using more space.

Some other types of ALTER TABLE, like dropping secondary keys, free up database pages in the tablespace, without rebuilding the table. But those pages are still held by the tablespace and recycled by subsequent data or indexes.

A tablespace never shrinks. It can only be dropped, or else defragmented as it's copied to a new tablespace.

So it's up to you to make sure there's at least enough free disk space to store an second copy of your largest table (plus binary logs if they are stored on the same volume, but I don't know if RDS stores binlogs on the same volume).

Comment: Ah, that will explain those giant temp files that were being created then!  thanks a lot.